# How can I append to a HTML table but keep the formatting I want via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this:

```
$.each( data.dbmatches, function(i, item) {
    $('#dbresults tbody').append('<tr><td>Accession</td><td>item.description</td></tr>');
});

$('#dbresults').show();
}
```

gives me an HTML table in the format I want:

```
Accession   item.description
```

However, `item.description` is a value from db matches, and no matter what variation I use with `append`, I do not end up with the same HTML table format. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#dbresults tbody').append('<tr><td>Description</td><td>').append(item.description).append('</td></tr>');
```

Result:

```
Accession
This is the description
```

This is the closest one, but the items are outside of the table cells, as if it's in the columns.

```
$('#dbresults tbody').append('<tr>').append('<td>','Description','</td>').append('<td>',item.description,'</td>').append('</tr>');
```

Result:

```
Accession    This is the description
```

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is *append* autoclose the tag , so the solution is concatenate:

```
$('#dbresults tbody').append('<tr><td>Description</td><td>'+item.description+'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Wow, I knew it was something simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use concatenation:

```
$.each( data.dbmatches, function(i, item) {
    $('#dbresults tbody').append('<tr><td>Accession</td><td>'+item.description+'</td></tr>');
    });
    $('#dbresults').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build the string with the description in it

```
$('#dbresults tbody').append('<tr><td>Description</td><td>'+item.description+'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 $('#dbresults tbody').append("<tr><td>Accession</td><td>"+item.description+"</td></tr>");
```